# What is appearance-based SLAM?

Tags: slam

To my understanding appearance-based SLAM uses **only** information coming from sensors for mapping and localization. It completely discards control information from actuators. I'm I correct?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics:SE. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Appearance-based SLAM methods model the set of discrete locations in a space and the existence of paths between these locations.

I suggest you first read this paper [Appearance based slam for mobile robot](http://eia.udg.es/~qsalvi/papers/2009-CCIA.pdf) . Try to know the basic idea behind the appearance based slam.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the localization approach on your **SLAM (Simultaneous localization and mapping)**, **i.e.  AMCL** localization algorithm using the laser (sensor) + wheels encoders (actuators sensors).

---

[**Note**]:

This algorithm based on adaptive Monte Carlo + EKF (extended Kalman filter)

[list of SLAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SLAM_Methods)

---

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? How does the localization approach make one algorithm appearance-based?

Comment: What do you mean by  "algorithm appearance-based"?